# Isolated table and foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design

I have got two questions when designing a database for a sales system.

1. Is it possible to have a isolated table, which means a table does not have relationship with all other tables?
2. How to solve the following issue:

   Table: SalesOrderDetail,  Table: InventoryTrans

   Every record in `SalesOrderDetail` will insert into `InventoryTrans`, but not all records in `InventoryTrans` are from `SalesOrderDetail`. Because other tables may also insert records into the `InventoryTrans`.

Therefore, I want to add a reference column `SalesOrderDetailID` to `InventoryTrans` table, but does not specify FK constraint. Because if the record is not from `SalesOrderDetail` table, then the `SalesOrderDetailID` should be null.

Is this the right design?

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please ask one question per post, so you can be answered in an organized fashion. You can also refer to [ask] for additional advise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a table that has no foreign key references to other tables. A table that stores various configuration settings is probably the most common, but there are others.

The column InventoryTrans.SalesOrderDetailID can be a nullable foreign key reference. But you haven't provided enough detail to tell whether that's a good design decision. Making an educated guess, I'd say probably not. (Other kinds of transactions would probably benefit from a foreign key reference.)